# Foreign Key hold values of Primay Key

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to design a Database for a Patient record.
I am stuck at one point when dealing with Medicine List.
"Table_Patient_Record" - is having a field - "Medicine_Ids" ...
and "Table_Medicine_Record" - having unique - "Id" & "Medicine_Name" ...

Now, my problem is, How to hold multiple(variable) "Id" of "Table_Medicine_Record" into "Medicine_Ids" of "Table_Patient_Record"?

Since, the number of medicines belong to a patient varies from other patients.
Then, how to design database so that from a UI we can Insert, Update and Select.

Thanks, I hope my question is to clear to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, you have a database 'Patients' and 'Medicines'.
The easiest solution is to create a table 'PatientMedicines' that holds a userid and a medicineid.

This way you can connect multiple patients to multiple medicines and the other way around.
And still leaves the freedom that a patient does not need to have any medicine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a many to many relationship to me. One patient can use multiple medicine, and a medicine can be used by multiple patients. Use a junction table that holds the patient id and the medicine id. Like this:

```
PatientId   | MedicineId
1               1
1               2
2               1
2               3
```